# Time complexity or Big O of the code

Tags: c, data-structures, time-complexity, heap, binary-heap

I have this array which has a max heap property. The time complexity of deleteMax is O(logn). If the code below will iterate for only 7 times, what would be the time complexity of the below code (big O)?

```
int heap_size = 15;
int i, value, heap_array[]; // array is in the form of max heap
....
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){ // iterates seven times
    value = deleteMax(heap_array);
    printf("%d ", value);
}
```

I have two solutions in my mind. First: The time complexity is O(7 * logn) or simply O(logn).

Then the second one is O(1/2 * n * logn) or O(nlogn) since 1/2 is just a constant and I'm assuming that since the number of iteration is 7 which is almost the same as the half the heap_size, I can disregard 1/2. Thus O(nlogn)

Which one would be correct?

Comment: If heap size is always 15, you have a constant time complexity here. O(1). It's not a function of the input, because there's no input.

Comment: @LukeLee  I think you need to consider the deleteMax function inside the for loop - O(logn) and also the number of iterations in the for loop? What I'm confused is that the for loop will only iterate up to 7 elements and not the whole heap_size.

Comment: Well you picked a bad example. If the for loop runs `n/2` times, that's more interesting.

Comment: It might be what you actually asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general it is pointless to talk about complexity when a number is fixed (aka constant). The whole purpose of the notation is to evaluate how execution time changes when a number changes. A constant number of loops will never change execution time nor complexity. If you change the number of loops to **another** constant value, it will change execution time **but** complexity is the same.

The typical use is to calculate the complexity of a function in order to give the user of the function an idea about how execution time changes when the user changes some input value. Example:

```
void foo()                 // Pointless to talk about complexity as there is no input

void foo(int x)            // Complexity tells you how execution time change 
                           // when you change x

void foo(char* someString) // Complexity tells you how execution time change 
                           // when you change the length of someString
```

Note: Complexity never tells you the actual execution time! Only how execution time changes when some input is changed.

So in your case, it is still `deleteMax` that determines complexity, i.e. it is still O(log n). Simply because there is no input changing the number of loops.

Comment: So, if I make i < 7 to i < 20 (assuming that this is error-free), the time complexity will still be O(logn) since it is not dependent on the size of the data? Am I correct with this one? Btw, answer accepted. Thanks

Comment: @labyrinthdeux Correct. Changing from 7 to 20 doesn't impact complexity. The notation is **not** for saying how long it takes to execute a piece of code. The notation tells youhow execution time changes when you change something, e.g. the length of an array that you give as input

Comment: @labyrinthdeux - But if you made the loop limit depend on something, e.g. `i < someInputValue`, then the complexity would change.

Comment: @4386427: I'd add that the complexity tells you how execution time changes when some input is changed, _for large inputs_. This is because we only keep the dominant term. If the execution time is given by T(n) = n^2 + 1000*n, the complexity is O(n^2), but the increase will be near linear for small ns. It is only for larger ns it becomes (near) quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

If the loop only runs 7 times then the complexity is O(1). This is for the reason that the loop does not depend on the size of the data and will always run in constant time.

Comment: So, if I make i < 7 to i < 20 (assuming that this is error-free), the time complexity will still be O(logn) since it is not dependent on the size of the data? Am I correct with this one?

Comment: @Archmede: If the loop runs a fixed number of times then the complexity will be _the same as that of deleteMax,_ which was stated to be O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

Here, both the heap size and number of times the loop runs are constant. So the code will have a time complexity of O(1), i.e., constant time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were leaning the heap sort algorithm, and I'm sure the complexity is O(nlogn).